# Flex3: Escaping Characters in XML

Tags: xml, flex3, escaping

I'm using Flex 3, SDk 3.6, Flash Player 10.

Flex is giving me syntax errors if I don't escape characters in my XML data. For example:

```
<mx:XML xmlns="">
       <group>
    <place stackName="Place1">
        <name>Place ABC</name>
        <encoding>ieqlFjiguM?_YHW\k@ZYd@UNAcA{AsGaLkJcRkAuBpm@BjBlJdBlJZ`@fCfBd@r@dFnMbCxF|B`Fn@fAmCViDHu@RoCnAsCfA}BhAe@`@OZu@fDSb@wAj@e@VUq@uB}@aAy@yCf@_AFs@i@Fe@y@}@Eo@c@@[[CcAQAk@ZQf@o@BIA?W</encoding>
    </place>
        </group>
</mx:XML>
```

In this case, the data surrounded by the  tags causes a problem. If I add a backslash to all of the special characters, then I don't get any errors, but I can't use it to make a google maps encoded polygon.

Edit:
These are the errors I'm getting:

1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before rightparen.
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before ampersand.
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen 
1093: Syntax error.
1093: Syntax error. 
Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace. [Generated code (use -keep to save)
Syntax error: expecting rightparen before rightbrace. [Generated code (use -keep to save)

Comment: XML doesn't use backslash to escape characters. Please post the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the message. These are the errors, I'm getting: 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before rightparen.  
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before ampersand. 
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen 
1093: Syntax error.  
1093: Syntax error. 
Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace. [Generated code (use -keep to save)
Syntax error: expecting rightparen before rightbrace. [Generated code (use -keep to save) It's definitely an escape issue. If I escape the weird characters, I don't get the errors. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Those seem like errors in your code, not in the XML. Besides, there are no right parens in the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use CDATA tags contain the content.

```
<mx:XML xmlns="">
    <group>
        <place stackName="Place1">
            <name>Place ABC</name>
            <encoding>
                <![CDATA[
                    ieqlFjiguM?_YHW\k@ZYd@UNAcA{AsGaLkJcRkAuBpm@BjBlJdBlJZ`@fCfBd@r@dFnMbCxF|B`Fn@fAmCViDHu@RoCnAsCfA}BhAe@`@OZu@fDSb@wAj@e@VUq@uB}@aAy@yCf@_AFs@i@Fe@y@}@Eo@c@@[[CcAQAk@ZQf@o@BIA?W
                ]]>
            </encoding>
        </place>
    </group>
</mx:XML>
```

Comment: Hi xavierzhao, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: What is it? Can you tell me the details?

Comment: Hi xavierzhao, You were right. I actually had another bug that was causing the problem. When I fixed the bug and added the CDATA tags it worked. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I followed this [tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/flex/flex-3-xml-contact-list/) and loaded the XML from an external file and it works. I must have screwed up how the XML was loaded.

Thank you John and xavierzhao for trying to help me.